# Node NPM SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm running into an issue that seems to be very popular with Node / NPM

None of my search results seems to address my issue exactly...

I'm using Restify & NodeJs...but a simple `npm run start` produces the following error...

```
import logger   from 'src/modules/amLogger.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

My packake.json file:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Me@me.com",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.2.1",
    "npm": ">=5.3.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "ascii-art": "^1.4.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-generator": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "canvas": "^1.6.6",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "documentation": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
    "restify": "^5.0.1",
    "restify-error": "^1.0.0",
    "restify-plugins": "^1.6.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "util": "^0.10.3",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ascii-art": "^1.4.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-generator": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.2.11",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas": "^6.20.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
    "canvas": "^1.6.6",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "compression": "^1.7.0",
    "documentation": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
    "restify": "^5.0.1",
    "restify-error": "^1.0.0",
    "restify-plugins": "^1.6.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "util": "^0.10.3",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "am:version": "/bin/sh scripts/display.sh",
    "am:pretty-error": "node --require pretty-error/start am.js",
    "am:start": "/bin/sh scripts/display.sh && node am.js",
    "start": "node am.js"
  },
  "description": "example",
  "main": "am.js"
}
```

Here is my am.js file

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
import logger   from 'src/modules/amLogger.js';
import chalk    from 'chalk';
import util     from 'util';

/**
 * Module Dependencies
 */
const restify   = require('restify'),
    winston     = require('winston'),
    errs        = require('restify-errors'),
    art         = require('ascii-art'),
    compression = require('compression');

// create the Restify Server
const server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'example',
    version: 'v0.0.1',
...
```

The error is happening at `import logger   from 'src/modules/amLogger.js';` however if I comment out this line the error simply moves to the next import statement -- I've also tried running this without the `'use strict';`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node doesnt support yet es6 imports here you have an article that explains it
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c